# Парсинг JSON на SWIFT

Tags: json, swift, swift4

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу подобрать структуру для декодинга данного JSON:

```
"cars": [
    { "name":"Ford", "models": "Fiesta", "color": "red" },
    { "name":"BMW", "models": "X5", "color": "green" },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models": "500", "color": "blue" }
]
```

В самом JSON массиве не будет точного количества элементов(тут их 3). 
И как после декодинга можно будет обращаться к элементам извлеченного массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON не валидный. Правильная структура JSON должна начинаться и заканчиваться фигурными скобками.

```
var str = """
{"cars": [
{ "name":"Ford", "models": "Fiesta", "color": "red" },
{ "name":"BMW", "models": "X5", "color": "green" },
{ "name":"Fiat", "models": "500", "color": "blue" }
]}
"""

struct Response: Codable {
    let cars: [Car]
}

struct Car: Codable {
    let name: String
    let models: String
    let color: String
}

let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: str.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Comment: Thanks, now everything works :)